# SSH and aliasing

Tags: ssh, alias

## Background

I'm a php developer who has started a new job. The company has numerous docker instances and the ability to spin multiple versions of this up, for example: to check a particular git branch etc. The system copies all relevant files as well as keys and access.

As these are spun up they end up with different ssh addresses. The usual command: `ssh user@someaddress.domain` works as expected.

However, I am operating multiple keys (so I can separately rotate and keep personal and private keys unrelated etc). All these spun up instances will use the same key

For this, I can use `ssh -i [path to key] [user@domain]`. Typing this every time is a hassle.

In bash, and with MySQL you can prompt for the username/password/whatever: `mysql -u -p` for example.
I have aliased or Bash scripted this to good effect many times.

I would like to alias `ssh_test` to be: `ssh -i [path to key]` and have it request for the address to save on a (lot) of typing.

## Question

How can I use the `ssh` command in such a way that it prompts for the address

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things - use `ssh-agent` and let that figure out which key is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `~/.ssh/config` file for this:

```
# everything else matches this
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server1
  Hostname server1.fqdn
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server1

Host server2
  Hostname server2.fqdn
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server2

Host server3
  Hostname server3.fqdn
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server3
```

So that when you, for instance, `ssh server2`, ssh client automatically picks up and uses the `~/.ssh/server2` key. Because it matches `Host server2` in the ssh config file above.

And if you do `ssh anyotherserver`, ssh client will automatically pick and use `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Because it matches `Host *` in the ssh config file above.

Comment: This would be useful, if the instance names didn't change constantly...

Comment: You can use regex in the ssh config file as well for the `Host`, in case there is a match for certain sets of servers. `man ssh_config` for more

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using bash you need to specify the key file below.

```
echo “alias ssh_test=‘ssh -i <path/key>’ >> ~/.bashrc
```